# Error 'no match for call to vector<int> normal_iterator<int*, vector<int> >::difference_type)'

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, shuffle

I'm trying to use this vector.h function:

```
 random_shuffle(s.begin()+from+i,s.begin()+to,s);
```

This error happens:

```
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|5255|error: no match for call to '(std::vector<int>) (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >::difference_type)'|
```

Any idea? Thank in advance!

Comment: There's no vector.h and `std::random_shuffle` is in `<algorithm>`, which has no ties to `std::vector`. `std::random_shuffle` was also deprecated in C++14 and will be removed in C++17. The preferred algorithm is `std::shuffle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter to `std::random_shuffle` (assuming you are talking about that, if not, please clarify your question) must be a

> function object returning a randomly chosen value of type convertible to `std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type` in the interval `[0,n)` if invoked as `r(n)`

(from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)), not a vector. You probably meant to use the two argument variant of the function:

```
random_shuffle(s.begin()+from+i,s.begin()+to);
```

Also, please note that `std::random_shuffle` is obsolete. You should be using [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) instead.